# Rails: one-to-many params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-many, parameters

I'm making a website for my sports team where players can make blog posts.

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :blogs, dependent: :destroy

end


class Blog < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :player

end
```

My question is:

What is the difference between setting up the route/controller action with the following two params? They are both giving me the exact same thing.

1)

route:

```
get "players/:player_id/posts" => "blogs#show", as: "player_posts"
```

controller action:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @player = Player.find(params[:player_id])
        @blogs = @player.blogs
    end
end
```

2)

route:

```
get "players/:id/posts" => "blogs#show", as: "player_posts"
```

controller action:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @player = Player.find(params[:id])
        @blogs = @player.blogs
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between setting up the route/controller action
>   with the following two params?

There is ***no difference*** between those two named routes, except you are using ***different keys***(`:player_id` & `:id`). I suggest the first route since you fetching ***players instance*** in the ***blogs controller***.

```
get "players/:player_id/posts" => "blogs#show", as: "player_posts"

#controller action:

class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @player = Player.find(params[:player_id]) #players instance
    @blogs = @player.blogs
  end
end
```